# Captcha not always displaying

Tags: php, captcha

I am creating a php website, my issue is - captcha is not showing on some page, but it display on some page, having same code on each page.

Below is the code I am using:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("captcha/simple-php-captcha.php");
    $_SESSION['captcha'] = captcha();
?>
<img  src="<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']['image_src']; ?>" alt="CAPTCHA" width="90" height="30px" >
```

but when I reload the page it displays correctly.

Comment: Please check out the Stackoverflow formatting guide for your code and correct your spelling mistakes.

Comment: @Simon - I agree that formatting is important. But, fwiw, where a contributor's first language is not English, and the question is still reasonably understandable, I tend to go easy on them (or fix the text transparently).

Comment: @Veger, I am puzzled as to why you edited the code snippet - clearly the one posted was incomplete, but surely for all you know what you have provided would work fine and not show the OP's problem?

Comment: @Vicky I only applied code formatting (and some grammar corrections). I did not change anything in the code itself (which would have been a bad thing). You can check for yourself by looking at the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14438598/revisions) while selecting the 'side-by-side markdown' view.

Comment: @Veger, my apologies - I didn't realise the failed markdown in the OP had eaten half the code as posted. I was looking at the "side by side" view but not "side by side markdown", so it looked as though you had added a bunch of code. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @halfer the initial post said "Plz help me sort this...". If you can type "Plz" you can type "Please" and keep the quality of the questions on an acceptable level.

Comment: @Simon, fair enough, I'd agree with that one! I'm not a fan of txtspk either.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth taking a look at [EM-Captcha](http://filesmelt.com/dl/EMCaptcha-1.0BETA_.zip) (PHP CAPTCHA class).

It includes [clear documentation](http://www.edwardmcknight.co.uk/?p=303) as to how to implement it.